# Tidyr syntax to replace sqldf queries

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data as below, which I wish to do exploratory analysis:

```
selected <- c("1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", NA)
teammember1 <- c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M")
teammember2 <- c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F")
teammember3 <- c("M", "M", "", "", "", "", "M", "", "M", "F", "")
selection <- data.frame(teammember1, teammember2, teammember3, selected)
```

I would wish to obtain a data frame showing the probability of being selected if a team has a female member vs not having a female member.

I have used *sqldf* queries as below:

```
 library(sqldf)
  selectcomp <- sqldf("SELECT  *
                  FROM selection
                  WHERE  selected NOT NULL
                  ")
      selectcomp
      countnotNull <- dplyr::count(selectcomp)

    withF <- sqldf("SELECT  *
                  FROM selectcomp
                  WHERE  (teammember1 LIKE '%F%'
                  OR teammember2 LIKE '%F%'
                  OR teammember3 LIKE '%F%')
                  AND selected LIKE '%1%'
                  ")

   onlyM <- sqldf("SELECT  *
                  FROM selectcomp
                  WHERE  (teammember1 NOT LIKE '%F%'
                  AND teammember2 NOT LIKE '%F%'
                  AND teammember3 NOT LIKE '%F%')
                  AND selected LIKE '%1%'
                 ")
  countwithF <- dplyr::count(withF)
  countonlyM <- dplyr::count(onlyM)

  probwithF <- (countwithF/countnotNull)*100
  probonlyM <- (countonlyM/countnotNull)*100

  comparison <- data.frame(probwithF, probonlyM)
  comparison
  colnames(comparison) <- c("probwithF", "probonlyM")

 library(tidyr)
 comparison <- comparison %>% 
 tidyr::gather(type, prob) 
 comparison
```

How would a scheme employing *tidyr* and *Magrittr* pipe (%>%) entirely, look like ?

Comment: Note that the first SQL statement and subsequent `count` can be written as `sqldf("select count(*)
  from selection
  where selected is not null and
        teammember1 is not null and
        teammember2 is not null and
        teammember3 is not null")` or even shorter
`where <- paste(paste(names(selection), "is not null"), collapse = " and ");
fn$sqldf("select count(*) from selection where $where")`

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce your desired output using `tidyverse` style like this:

```
selection %>% 
  mutate(selected = as.numeric(as.character(selected))) %>%
  mutate(team_type = if_else((teammember1=="F" | teammember2=="F" |teammember3=="F"),
                             "Team with F","Team without F")) %>% 
  group_by(team_type) %>% 
  summarise(probabilty = mean(selected, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The probability for "Team with F" is 20% because 2 of the 10 teams for which you have the relevant information are marked as selected **AND** have at least one female in the team.

But is this really what you want to know? I understood that you like to know the probability of being selected, given that you have or don't have a female in your team. Then your code would be:

```
selection %>% 
  mutate(selected = as.numeric(as.character(selected))) %>%
  mutate(count_not_na = sum(!is.na(selected))) %>%
  mutate(team_type = if_else((teammember1=="F" | teammember2=="F" |teammember3=="F"), 
                             "Team with F","Team without F")) %>% 
  group_by(team_type) %>% 
  summarise(probabilty = sum(selected/count_not_na, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The probability for "Team with F" is now 50%, because 2 of the 4 teams with female participation and information about the selection status are actually marked as selected.

Comment: your solution gives a 0.5 probability for both cases, while I am getting a 0.3 for the team with F and 0.2 for Team without F. I am looking to be able to exclude NULL in the selected column that is why I put it as character. What part you cannot reproduce?